# Sql Grouping by change Date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that gives a history on an object. One row for each change.
For my task, I am only interested in one changed field: STATUS. Here is a sample of the table, narrowed down to one object with many columns omitted:

| OBJECT_ID | STATUS | CHANGE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 173129 | P | 2020-11-05 |
| 173129 | A | 2020-10-25 |
| 173129 | A | 2020-03-15 |
| 173129 | A | 2019-08-29 |
| 173129 | P | 2019-08-29 |
| 173129 | A | 2019-06-07 |
| 173129 | A | 2018-12-02 |
| 173129 | A | 2018-09-01 |
| 173129 | A | 2018-07-29 |
| 173129 | A | 2018-03-13 |
| 173129 | A | 2018-02-15 |

I would need to group these entities somehow to find out when Status was changed and ignore other rows.

So what I done is:

```
select OBJECT_ID ,
       STATUS ,
       MIN(CHANGE_DATE ) AS
           CHANGE_DATE 
FROM HISTORIC
GROUP BY OBJECT_ID , STATUS 
order by OBJECT_ID  desc, CHANGE_DATE  desc
```

This worked for a while, but then it turns out that Status can change multiple times from A (active) to P (pending), then back and forth again. There are several more possible values for STATUS.

The dates when an object becomes pending for the last time matters to me more at the moment, while my query gets me the first time a status changed.

My expected result could be one out of two things:

1. a table with all status change rows:

| OBJECT_ID | STATUS | CHANGE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 173129 | P | 2020-11-05 |
| 173129 | A | 2019-08-29 |
| 173129 | P | 2019-08-29 |
| 173129 | A | 2018-02-15 |

2. a table with the latest status changes for a particular STATUS:

| OBJECT_ID | STATUS | CHANGE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 173129 | P | 2020-11-05 |
| 173129 | A | 2019-08-29 |

I have quite a few complicated requirements, such as

- All objects which were active at a certain date but have been set to pending in the meantime

Comment: If someone can think of a better title for this question, feel free to change it.

Comment: Please, show us your expected result for the data sample above.

Comment: What did you tried so far? `LAG` analytic function is your friend;)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first resultset with `lag()`:

```
select *
from (
    select h.*,
        lag(status) over(partition by object_id order by change_date) as lag_status
    from historic h
) h
where lag_status is null or lag_status <> status
```

The idea is to compare the status on each row to that of the "previous" row, and exhibit rows where they are not equal.

Note that this only works as long as you have a column that unambiguously defines the ordering of the rows for each group of `object_id`s. I used `change_date`, but in your data there are ties. Since you are using Oracle, I assumed that these dates have a time portion, that is not showed here, and that allows breaking the ties. If that's not the case, you need to figure out which column can be used to break the ties, and add it to the `order by` clause of `lag()`.

Comment: The dates have a time portion but it is always 00:00:00 so I omitted it here.

I had not even realized that a status was changed twice in one day with no way of ordering. That will cause me grief. The data comes to us through a pipeline of different systems and somewhere along the line somebody decided that the time of change was not important (*facepalm*)

Answer (score 2):

A table with all status change rows:

```
with previous_statuses$ as (
    select X.*,
        lag(status) over (partition by object_id order by change_date) as prev_status
    from historic X
)
select object_id, status, change_date
from previous_statuses$
where status != prev_status
    or prev_status is null
;
```

If you want only the last change of status, then

```
with previous_statuses$ as (
    select X.*,
        lag(status) over (partition by object_id order by change_date) as prev_status
    from historic X
)
select object_id,
    max(status) keep (dense_rank last order by change_date),
    max(change_date)
from previous_statuses$
where status != prev_status
    or prev_status is null
group by object_id;
```

A table with the latest status changes for a particular STATUS:

```
with previous_statuses$ as (
    select X.*,
        lag(status) over (partition by object_id order by change_date) as prev_status
    from historic X
)
select object_id, status,
    max(change_date)
from previous_statuses$
where status != prev_status
    or prev_status is null
group by object_id, status;
```

Comment: What's with the `$` convention? Do you only use that for CTE aliases, or..?

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile and addressing all my stated expectations

Comment: @kfinity, just to mark something unusual, out of the ordinary. In this case, yes, visually distinguishing CTEs from regular tables.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can do it using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

## Latest change for each status:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   historic
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY object_id
  ORDER     BY change_date
  MEASURES
    LAST( active.change_date )  AS last_active,
    LAST( pending.change_date ) AS last_pending
  PATTERN ( pending* active* pending* $ )
  DEFINE
    active     AS status = 'A',
    pending    AS status = 'P'
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> OBJECT_ID | LAST_ACTIVE         | LAST_PENDING       
> --------: | :------------------ | :------------------
>    173129 | 2020-11-05 00:00:00 | 2019-08-29 00:00:00
> ```

Or just use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT object_id,
       status,
       MAX( CHANGE_DATE ) AS change_date
FROM   historic
GROUP BY
       object_id,
       status;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> OBJECT_ID | STATUS | CHANGE_DATE        
> --------: | :----- | :------------------
>    173129 | P      | 2019-08-29 00:00:00
>    173129 | A      | 2020-11-05 00:00:00
> ```

## All status changes:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   historic
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY object_id
  ORDER     BY change_date
  MEASURES
    FIRST( status )     AS status,
    LAST( change_date ) AS change_date
  PATTERN ( same_status+ )
  DEFINE same_status AS FIRST( status ) = status
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> OBJECT_ID | STATUS | CHANGE_DATE        
> --------: | :----- | :------------------
>    173129 | A      | 2019-08-29 00:00:00
>    173129 | P      | 2019-08-29 00:00:00
>    173129 | A      | 2020-11-05 00:00:00
> ```

For your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE historic ( OBJECT_ID, STATUS, CHANGE_DATE ) AS
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2020-11-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2020-10-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2020-03-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2019-08-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'P', DATE '2019-08-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2019-06-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2018-12-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2018-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2018-07-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2018-03-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 173129, 'A', DATE '2018-02-15' FROM DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e3cc2276bf71d6f9d21a66af3be80bf)*